# Get value of all span elements within a ul

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get value of all span elements with class 'pull-left' inside a ul li tag.
Below is my tried code but I am getting an empty list.
Where am I going wrong ?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">                              
        </script>
        <script>
            var textArray = $('.order-review ul li h3').find('span.pull-left').map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            console.log(textArray);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="order-review">
             <h2 class="color text-center">your </h2>
             <ul class="order-summary"><li><h3><span class="pull-left">food</span><span class="pull-right color">×1</span></h3></li></ul>
             <ul class="order-summary"><li><h3><span class="pull-left">food1</span><span class="pull-right color">×1</span></h3></li></ul>                        
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Follow this link : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty common problem...

You need to wrap your functionality in a jQuery ready function.

your code should look like this:

```
$(function()
{
    var textArray = $('.order-review ul li h3').find('span.pull-left').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    console.log(textArray);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

If I put your code into [a jsfiddle document](https://jsfiddle.net/o1gu6uwp/), it's working. If you want to keep your js at the same place, you'll have to put wrap your code this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your JS code
});
```

This will execute the javascript when the DOM tree is completely loaded.